# Написать один селектор для нескольких элементов дива

Tags: css, test-automation, css-selectors

На сайте https://github.com/, если пролистать в самый низ, есть один очень интересный div.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне написать селектор, который выберет сразу все эти элементы, без заголовков Product, Platform...

Comment: Какие варианты вы пробовали и они не сработали?

Comment: А для чего вам это? Скорее всего то что вам нужно можно сделать проще

Comment: @hot_penguin вопрос на собеседовании задали такой, спросил потом как это сделать - ответили что нужно закомбинировать их общие элементы как-то и получится

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Вроде получилось, вот икс пас селектор //div[@class='d-flex flex-wrap py-5 mb-5']/div[not(contains(@class,'col-12 col-lg-4 mb-5'))], но тут с заголовками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
footer ul li.lh-condensed.mb-3 {

}
```

И будет тем самым селектором. **Последовательное упоминание через пробел означает вложенность, классы через точку помогают дополнительно уточнить.** Скорее всего это и имелось в виду под закомбинировать - теги находятся в футере, в списках...

чтобы проверить работу можно ввести в консоли

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('footer ul li.lh-condensed.mb-3')].map(e => e.textContent)
```

> [   "Features",   "Security",   "Team",   "Enterprise",   "Customer
> stories",   "The ReadME Project",   "Pricing",   "Resources",
> "Roadmap",   "Developer API",   "Partners",   "Atom",   "Electron",
> "GitHub Desktop",   "Docs",   "Community Forum",   "Professional
> Services",   "Learning Lab",   "Status",   "Contact GitHub",
> "About",   "Blog",   "Careers",   "Press",   "Inclusion",   "Social
> Impact" ]

Answer (score 2):

У меня получился вот такой `footer > .container-xl ul li a`